# eclipse errors exist in required projects but editor shows no errors

Tags: java, eclipse

I use eclipse to code in java. My code was running perfectly fine. Finally, i deleted some files which were not needed from my drive.

Right now, I have the source file and the compiled .class files in the correct folders. Also, although I initially had multiple .java files, I am 100% sure that the one I need is there and  also that it doesn't need anything from any other thing. All the imports (i import only from standard libraries) are showing no error.

**The problem is that when i make any changes in my .java file, and save it, it does get saved but when I execute the code, it runs just like the old version, i.e. the changes are not reflected in the output.** Also, on clicking 'run', eclipse gives a warning that 'errors exist in required projects' although the editor shows none.

Whats going wrong ? Please help.

Comment: Try to clean your project and build again.

Comment: I now deleted my .class file (had the main method) and now when i save the .java file in eclipse, a new .class file doesn't appear in the folder.

Comment: Don't delete them manually. Let eclipse clean up the things for you.

Comment: i cleaned the project, saved the .java file again but still the .class file doesn't appear.

Comment: i'll keep that in mind. but is there something that i can do now ?

Comment: Build the project now. Just saving a file won't build it(unless you've the build automatically enabled).

Comment: I do have the build automatically enabled....doesn't help. I disabled it and clicked 'build all' and then 'build project' also....but the .class file isn't created.

Answer (score 14):

Okay got it....I had added some external jars to my project. Later, when I realised that they were not needed anymore, i deleted them from my hard disk. However, the build path contained their names too among the other libraries  (and displayed "missing" after that). I removed them and its working fine.